# Cannot connect to the Rpc server

Tags: solidity

I am unable to deploy the smart contract from my vs code .

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "HTTP://172.27.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "private key",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./debt_sol_simplestorage.abi", "utf-8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync("./debt_sol_simplestorage.bin", "utf-8");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.contractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying please wait");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I have connected the ganache but when i open the Rpc server in the browser ,it says 404 error . and also when running `node deploy.js` the following error occured.

```
    at main (/home/divyanshu/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:4:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/divyanshu/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

Also I am using the Wsl ,so I installed the ganache in the terminal itself with `yarn add ganache` and `yarn run ganache` ,it was runnning ,but still I could not find my mistake .And the error is there after trying everything from the net also.
Can somebody please help.

Comment: I think the endpoint should be something like:
"http://127.0.0.1:8545" or "http://localhost:8545"
Where did you get "HTTP://172.27.0.1:7545"?

Comment: but after removin https also ,the error is still there ,and on opening the url on browser still there is ```404 not found ```

Comment: Additional information that could be helpful includes details about any specific error messages received when attempting to connect to the RPC server and any troubleshooting steps that have already been attempted. Additionally, verifying that Ganache is running correctly and listening on the specified port would be useful information.